# Using Dockerfile RUN to clone a bitbucket repo

Tags: git, docker, dockerfile, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a bitbucket repository from a dockerfile when running

```
docker build -t newapi .
```

So far the Dockerfile it looks like

```
FROM node:alpine
EXPOSE 3000
RUN git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git
```

If I run the git clone command by itself in a console it works, already tested it, I'm using it in the form

```
git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git
```

And I tried to use the RUN command in many ways which give me different errors:

1.

```
 RUN git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git
```

Throws:

```
Step 6/13 : RUN git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git
---> Running in 9a748f75ff66
/bin/sh: git: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

2.

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git"]
```

Throws:

```
Step 6/13 : RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git"]
---> Running in dc7c373071c2
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
```

3.

```
RUN ["git", "clone", "https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git"]
```

Throws:

```
Step 6/13 : RUN ["git", "clone", "https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git"]
 ---> Running in b797b442d1fc
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"git\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

4.

```
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git"]
```

Throws:

```
Step 6/13 : RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git"]
 ---> Running in 2fe387a213f3
/bin/sh: git: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c git clone https://user:password@bitbucket.org/something/api.git' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I don't know what to try anymore, I tried using bash because some people say it works better with git, tried using the raw code which is run with "/bin/sh -c" before it. Is there a way to just execute "git clone..." and avoid the command to be prepended with something? Or what is the way to do what I'm trying to do?

I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14 and Docker Version 18.06.1-ce-mac73 (26764) if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install the git package:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache git
```

Comment: It threw:
    Step 6/14 : RUN apk --no-cache git
     ---> Running in 48f2b744cd6a
    ERROR: '--no-cache' is not an apk command. See 'apk --help'.
The command '/bin/sh -c apk --no-cache git' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: ok I checked the apk docs and the correct command is RUN apk add --no-cache git, however I can't edit your answer (min 6 characters error), edit it or post a new one and I'll accept it